# It really hertz while listening

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

[image]
Listen to the following mp3 puzzle:

https://soundcloud.com/infinite-stream/this-melody-hertz-my-ears

Comment: We don't allow puzzles to require off-site resources due to the possibility of link rot. Could you make this puzzle self-contained somehow? Puzzling wants all puzzles to be solvable in the future; can you guarantee that the link will _never_ go down?

Comment: I understand your concern but I could not attach an mp3 file in self contained way. I can take guarantee link will never go down as long as my google account does not go down. And I believe that it will be the same for future.

Comment: [Several](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6291/69582) [relevant](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6300/69582) [meta](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6506/69582) [answers](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6070/69582) with the same conclusion: puzzles really need to be self-contained, unless there is absolutely no other way and there is absolutely no possibility of the link going down. Another concern, for answers: they have to say "this was in the audio file" without any way to check them except for listening to the file (which I don't want to do).

Comment: I followed [this](https://video.meta.stackexchange.com/a/176) answer but it didn't convert into embedded audio player. :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word you are looking for is:

> Adage

Reason:

> The musical notes on the music file follow this order A,D,A,G,E in Concert Pitch, repeated twice. This spells the word.  An interesting fact is that an Adage is a short statement which aptly describes the nature of the melody.